# Find nondiagonalizable matrix A

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

Find nondiagonalizable matrix A such that matrix $A^2-6A$ is diagonizible.

Simpliest nondiagonizable matrix is a Jordan block 2 by 2  $\begin{pmatrix}
a & 1\\ 
0 & a
\end{pmatrix}$.

$\begin{pmatrix}
a & 1\\ 
0 & a
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
a & 1\\ 
0 & a
\end{pmatrix} -6\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
a & 1\\ 
0 & a
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a^2-6a & 2a-6\\ 
0 & a^2-6a
\end{pmatrix}$ is also nondiagonizable.

Is it possible to find such a matrix?

Comment: Can't you set $a=3$?

Comment: YeSSS! What about 3 by 3 matrix?

Comment: Take the $3 \times 3$ matrix where the upper left block is the $2 \times 2$ matrix that we found.

Comment: I forgot to add that the the other entries that are not on the diagonal should be $0$.